# sql server subquery errors

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a sql query as follows:

```
        select c.custid,
               q.quoteid,
        (case when oh.ref when '0 then 'D'
               else 'Q' END),
            SUM(oh.ref when '0' then 1
              when oh.ref>=100 &&
                   oh.ref<=999 then '1'
                   else '0'
                   end)
            from customer as c
            inner join quote as q
            on c.custid= q.custid
            inner join order as o
            on oh.orderid= o.orderid
            inner join orderhistory as oh
            on oh.orderid=o.orderid
```

can you guys tell me if there is something wrong with my subquery? 
                I am getting errors as follows.:
                1. the multipart identifier q.quoteid cannot be bound.\
                2. the multipart identifier c.custid cannot be bound 
                3. the multipart identifier oh.ref cannot be bound
                4. incorrect syntax near when.
                   please help and let me know if you need further information.

```
       I edited my question as follows: 

                select c.custid,
               q.quoteid,
               (CASE oh.ref WHEN '0' THEN 'D'
               ELSE 'Q' END),
               SUM(CASE oh.ref WHEN '0' THEN '1'
               WHEN oh.ref >=100 &&
                   oh.ref <=999 THEN '1'
                   ELSE '0'
                   END)
                FROM customer AS c
                INNER JOIN quote  AS q
                ON c.custid = q.custid
                INNER JOIN order AS o
                ON oh.orderid=o.orderid
                INNER JOIN orderhistory AS oh
                ON oh.orderid = o.orderid;

               now the error is being shown at the >= ,&&, <= symbols(incorrect syntax).
```

Comment: Looks like you have a simple typo - `'0 then` should be `'0' then`.

Comment: I cross checked my actual query and it doesn't have any typos. Not able to analyze what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. AND instead of &&
2. GROUP BY missing

   ```
   select  c.custid,
       q.quoteid,
       (CASE oh.ref WHEN '0' THEN 'D' ELSE 'Q' END),
       SUM(CASE oh.ref
            WHEN '0' THEN '1'
               WHEN oh.ref >=100 
            AND  oh.ref <=999  
               THEN '1'
               ELSE '0'
               END)
   FROM    customer AS c
       INNER JOIN quote  AS q      ON c.custid = q.custid
   INNER JOIN order AS o       ON oh.orderid =o.orderid
   INNER JOIN orderhistory AS oh   ON oh.orderid = o.orderid
   GROUP BY
   c.custid,
       q.quoteid,
       (CASE oh.ref WHEN '0' THEN 'D' ELSE 'Q' END)
   ```